# C# command line compiling - change incode value

Tags: c#, build, compilation

I'm trying to create a command line compiling command that will also change one of the code value.

I'm trying to compile the code with the user's token embedded in the code so he/she would be able to use the app right after download.

in my code I have the following line:

```
UserToken = HWMX-HJPL-L1TN-E62Y-2JCVK;
```

Currently I made an ugly workaround - I have created a script that look for a the plain text "HWMX-HJPL-L1TN-E62Y-2JCVK" replace it with the new token, and then calls the compiler to create the executable file.

Is there a "normal" way to directly change this value by passing it in the command line to the compiler?

Comment: Isn't it better to put the code in an external file? You can always fall-back on the hardcoded value if the external file does not exist, such as right after the users download the application.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is as follows:

1. Create a resource file for the project
2. Add a normal text file as a resource to the resource file
3. Place the user-token in the resource file, as the only content
4. Read the user-token as follows:

   ```
   string UserToken = Resources.Default.UserTokenFile;
   ```
5. Create a script that simply overwrites the file with the new user-token, before you compile the project